# IHttpModule not being invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my program I need to check the each request and if there is `language` parameter in the url need to get it and save in the session. Here is my code. Everything works fine in the VS 2010 development server. But when I try to debug in the IIS 7, `public void Init(HttpApplication context)` method not getting call. any idea?

**Globalizer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;

public class Globalizer : IHttpModule
{    
  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
  {
    context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(setLanguage);
  }

  public void Dispose(){}

  public void setLanguage(Object sender, EventArgs i_eventArgs)
  {
    HttpApplication http_application = sender as HttpApplication;
    string language = http_application.Request.Params["language"];

    if (language == "en" || language == "ja" || language == "zh" || language == "th")
    {     
      http_application.Session["language"] = language;
    }
    else
    {
      language = (string)http_application.Session["language"];
    }
    var l_culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = l_culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = l_culture;
  }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"  enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="LanguageSettingModule" type="Globalizer, App_Code" />
    </httpModules> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>    
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me.

```
<configuration> 
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"  enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="Globalizer" type="Globalizer" />
    </httpModules> 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>    
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name = "Globalizer" type="Globalizer"/>
        </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```